# These are all right? - One, Which, Something

Tags: sentence-construction

I'm writing something and I know that if someone wants to add some ideas or phrases after the sentence finished, we could do it by adding **one, something, which.**
So, are the sentences that I've written all right to use in a conversation situation? and here's a context.

" One of the happiest moment I’ve had was when I was doing something enthusiastically, like a contest, a relationship with a girl, studying English.
If I look back, whatever it is, the happiest moment is when I find myself enthusiastically doing something.
It is only when I’m doing something enthusiastically that I can feel alive. "

> 1. But sometimes it is hard that I’m in a state of being enthusiastic, one that I really want to be in.
> 2. But sometimes it is hard that I’m in a state of being enthusiastic, something that I really want to be in.
> 3. But sometimes it is hard that I’m in a state of being enthusiastic, which I really want to be in.
> 4. But sometimes it is hard that I’m in a state of being enthusiastic and that's something that I really want to be in.

PS. here, one, something, which, that means the state of being enthusiastic.

Comment: You feel ***'lively'***. You never feel 'alive' unless you are being saved from the deadliest monsters in *[Pandora](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Pandora)*. :P

Comment: @MaulikV: I absolutely disagree. If I feel *lively* I'm animated and funny and perhaps a bit excited. If I feel *alive* I feel myself more intensely. There is a reason these self-help books are titeled like ["Forty-five Ways to Feel Alive"](https://books.google.de/books?id=PdzpAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&dq=feel+alive&hl=de&sa=X&ei=ciQ_VeLYA431aO2QgKgO&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=feel%20alive&f=false), not " ...to Feel Lively"

Comment: But not here! I related 'enthusiasm' with 'liveliness'. There, I cannot think of using 'feeling alive'. @Stephie

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, *all* of your phrasings are sensible. There is no difference in meaning or tone.

Choose whichever one seems the most natural to you.